# Wordpress: sorting archive by custom field no thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-fields

I'm trying to sort every Wordpress archive by a custom field and so I add an action to my functions file, but I have two problems:

1. It shows only posts which have this custom field, I want it shows every post, but first the ones whoch have this field;
2. It doesn't show post thumbnails.

My action is this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 
function my_change_sort_order($query){
    if(is_archive())
    {

        // validate
        if( is_admin() )
        {
            return $query;
        }

        $query->set('meta_key', 'my_custom_field');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');    
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');


        return $query;
    }
};
```

As suggested by itzmekhokan I've tried also this:

```
$meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( //check meta_key exist
            'key' => 'my_custom_field',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        array( //if no meta_key exist
            'key' => 'my_custom_field',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set('meta_key', 'my_custom_field');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');    
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
```

Then I've tried this:

```
$meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array( //check meta_key exist
                'key' => 'my_custom_field',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            array( //if no meta_key exist
                'key' => 'my_custom_field',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'my_custom_field');    
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
```

Always without success. Wordpress shows only posts which have this field set.

Comment: pass relation as 'OR' to fetch all data@Alessandro Pietrantonio

Comment: thanks fro yoru reply @ParthMahida but I have to pass "OR" what?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 

function my_change_sort_order($query){

if(is_archive())
{
    // validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return $query;
    }

    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( //check meta_key exist
            'key' => 'my_custom_field',
            'compare' => '!=',
            'value' => ''
        ),
        array( //if no meta_key exist
            'key' => 'my_custom_field',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set('meta_key', 'my_custom_field');
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');    
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');


    return $query;
}
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've tried to use your function but nothing has changed.. it show only posts which have my_custom_field

Answer (score 0):

you need to add empty value, where you have array with 'NOT EXISTS' compare key value:

```
          array( //if no meta_key exist
                'key' => 'my_custom_field',
                'value'=>'',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
```

Also, try changing array where you have 'EXISTS' into this:

```
  array( //check meta_key exist
        'key' => 'my_custom_field',
        'value'=> 'somerandomvalue123456', //value that obviously won't be in records at all 
        'compare' => '<>'
    ),
```

This way, construction of query will consider 'NOT EXISTS' part, since value key is not missing, and it would search for other posts, that have such meta key, but don't have some random value you have set in query. 
There is a specific bug for this: 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23268#comment:22 and was existing in version 4.1, not sure if exists still, since there is no comment in ticket that points out to that problem is actually solved.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it gives always the same: only posts with custom field and no thumbnails...another thing I've noticed now: also menu items disappear..